# JSON created with PHP's json_encode results in parse errors

Tags: php, json

Take the following PHP array:

```
$arr = array(
    'about' => 'Ai você fala o seguinte: "- Mas vocês acabaram isso?" Vou te falar: -"Não, está em andamento!" Tem obras que "vai" durar pra depois de 2010. Agora, por isso, nós já não desenhamos, não começamos a fazer projeto do que nós "podêmo fazê"? 11, 12, 13, 14...',
    'construction' => 100,
);
```

When parsed to JSON with PHP's `json_encode`, I get the following string:

```
[{"about": "Ai você fala o seguinte: \"- Mas vocês acabaram isso?\" Vou te falar: -\"Não, está em andamento!\" Tem obras que \"vai\" durar pra depois de 2010. Agora, por isso, nós já não desenhamos, não começamos a fazer projeto do que nós \"podêmo fazê\"? 11, 12, 13, 14...", "construction": 100}]
```

Note that the **double quotes** in the original string get escaped with a backslash. It looks good and even [validates](http://jsonlint.com/).

When I try to parse the JSON in Chrome or Safari (using `JSON.parse()`), I get the following error in the console:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`

Firefox gives me:

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 39 of the JSON data`

From the Firefox error, I gather the first escaped double quote in the string seems to break the code.

If I manually escape the **backslashes** before the quotes, I get the expected object...

How can I prevent this error? Am I doing something wrong?

---

Relevant code:

### Model:

```
// Returns an array with basic enterprise information
public function getBasicInfo($destination = null)
{
    $response = array(
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'category' => ! empty($this->category_id) ? $this->category->name : '',
        'neighborhood' => ! empty($this->neighborhood) ? $this->neighborhood : '',
        'city' => (! empty($this->city) ? $this->city : '') . (! empty($this->state_id) ? (! empty($this->city) ? ', ' : '') . $this->state->abbreviation : ''),
        'dorms' => $this->dormitories_text,
        'area' => $this->area,
        'status' => ! empty($this->status_id) ? $this->status->name : '',
        'price' => $this->price > 0 ? 'R$ ' . number_format($this->price, 2, ',', '.') : '',
        'installment' => $this->installment > 0 ? 'R$ ' . number_format($this->installment, 2, ',', '.') : '',
        'image' => ! empty($this->card_image_id) && is_object($this->card_image) ? $this->card_image->getUrl() : '',
        'logo' => ! empty($this->logo_image_id) && is_object($this->logo_image) ? $this->logo_image->getUrl() : '',
        'permalink' => $this->getPermalink($destination),
        'about' => ! empty($this->about) ? $this->get_html($this->about) : '',
        'construction' => $this->getLatestConstructionStageProgress(),
    );
    return $response;
}
```

### Controller:

```
    // Build data array
    $json = array();
    foreach ($enterprises as $enterprise) {
        $json[] = $enterprise->getBasicInfo(REALTOR_URL);
    }
    $json = json_encode($json);

    // Build data array
    $data = array(
        'urlOrigin'     => $this->url_origin(),
        'module'        => 'Portal do Corretor - Empreendimentos',
        'categories'    => \Type::getByType('category'),
        'cities'        => \Enterprise::getUniqueCities(),
        'statuses'      => \Type::getByType('status'),
        'prices'        => \Enterprise::$priceRanges,
        'installments'  => \Enterprise::$installmentRanges,
        'neighborhoods' => $neighborhoods,
        'json'          => $json,
        'filters'       => (object) array(
            'search'        => isset($_POST['search']) && ! empty($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : null,
            'city'          => isset($_POST['city']) && ! empty($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : null,
            'neighborhood'  => isset($_POST['neighborhood']) && ! empty($_POST['neighborhood']) ? $_POST['neighborhood'] : null,
            'category'      => isset($_POST['category']) && ! empty($_POST['category']) ? intval($_POST['category']) : null,
            'dormitories'   => isset($_POST['dormitories']) && ! empty($_POST['dormitories']) ? intval($_POST['dormitories']) : null,
            'status'        => isset($_POST['status']) && ! empty($_POST['status']) ? intval($_POST['status']) : null,
        ),
        'sectionId'     => 'empreendimentos',
    );
    // Merge default values with the data array
    $data = array_merge($data, $this->getDefaultValues());

    // Returns the view with the data array
    return $this->view(REALTOR_URL . DS . 'empreendimentos', $data);
```

### View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var enterprises = '<?php echo $json; ?>';
</script>
```

### JavaScript:

```
if ($('#enterprises') && $('#enterprise-template').length && 'undefined' !== typeof enterprises) {
    enterprises = JSON.parse(enterprises);
    enterprisesCount = enterprises.length;
}
```

Comment: show your js code. if the json string you have above validates, then something ELSE is corrupting it.

Comment: Added relevant code snippets. Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: json is already valid javascript, so youc ould just have `var foo = <?php echo $json ?>;`. no need for  dumping into a `'` string and then parsing separately. however, since your string is getting corrupted, it'd still get corruped this other way anyways - have you CONFIRMED that you have correct character sets everywhere? e.g. if you're building the json in a (say) win-1252 charset environment, then dumping into a utf-8 page, you'll get mangled characters.

Comment: @MarcB: You're correct. Removing the single quotes works, but the problem persists. Yes. I am using UTF-8 everywhere. Could you run `JSON.parse('[{"about": "Ai você fala o seguinte: \"- Mas vocês acabaram isso?\" Vou te falar: -\"Não, está em andamento!\" Tem obras que \"vai\" durar pra depois de 2010. Agora, por isso, nós já não desenhamos, não começamos a fazer projeto do que nós \"podêmo fazê\"? 11, 12, 13, 14...", "construction": 100}]');` in your console? If you get the same error, we can rule out encoding issues.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that quotes in `var foo = <?php echo $json ?>;` are **needed**. It's a string. No quotes gets me a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o` error.

Comment: that's because your json is corrupted. json **IS** valid javascript. if your json string was valid, then `var foo = [{....}];` would be perfectly acceptable/valid javascript.

Comment: @MarcB: You're correct. Sorry. My mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not doing anything "wrong". In fact you have already found the solution yourself! The PHP-generated string is presumably transferred to JavaScript by `echo`-ing it into a line of JavasScript code using something like

```
var jsvar='<?= json_encode($arr) ?>';
```

The result will look more or less like you have shown in your post:

```
var js_var='[{"about": "Ai você fala o seguinte: \"- Mas vocês acabaram isso?\" Vou te falar: -\"Não, está em andamento!\" Tem obras que \"vai\" durar pra depois de 2010. Agora, por isso, nós já não desenhamos, não começamos a fazer projeto do que nós \"podêmo fazê\"? 11, 12, 13, 14...", "construction": 100}]';
```

When JavaScript parses this string the `\` before the `"` will be 'eaten up' and the JSON-string to be parsed by `JSON.parse` will look like:

```
'{"about":"Ai você fala o seguinte: "- Mas vocês acabaram isso?" Vou te falar: -"Não, está em andamento!" Tem obras que "vai" durar pra depois de 2010. Agora, por isso, nós já não desenhamos, não começamos a fazer projeto do que nós "podêmo fazê"? 11, 12, 13, 14...","construction":100}'
```

This string will understandably lead to error messages.

**Solution:**

So, what you will have to do is mask all your `\` with `addslashes()`:

```
var jsvar='<?= addslashes(json_encode($arr)) ?>';
var o=JSON.parse(jsvar);
```

Or, as @JAAulde quite correctly posted: you can skip the `string'-state of the variable altogether by doing directly:

```
var o=<?= json_encode($arr)) ?>;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because JSON uses a subset of JS literal syntax, echoing it straight into the context of JS does not require any quote wrapping or parsing.

Outputting like this:

```
var enterprises = <?php echo $json; ?>;
```

Will cause the variable, `enterprises`, to be the data structure you desire once JS executes. As such, you also need to remove this line:

```
enterprises = JSON.parse(enterprises);
```

FWIW, your original error is caused by the need to double escape slashes in JS string literals. Because you outputted into a string literal, the single `\"` is eaten up in the JavaScript execution and is no longer there for the JSON parse. To output into a JS string literal you would first need to escape the escapes. Thus, you should stick with my above changes (not to mention that my recommended changes require less overhead).

Comment: This is incorrect. PHP's `json_encode` generates a string. I need the quotes around the `<?php echo $json; ?>` so that JS will understand it's a string. Not adding quotes generates a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o` error.

Comment: @AlexandreReiffJanini You have a fundamental misunderstanding of the mechanics involved. Try what I said, you'll see. (All outputted data from PHP to the browser is a string being passed into various contexts. You don't wrap your outputted HTML in quotes just because they're a string in PHP...). Also, take note of the edit to your accepted answer.

Comment: I have tested `var o=<?=json_encode($arr)?>;` - it *does* work!